# Ubuntu: Pointing an SFTP user to its working directory without listing other user's directory

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, sftp, chroot, account-restrictions

I am working on configuring an SFTP server on Ubuntu Server 18.04. I want to create SFTP accounts that point directly to their working directory without listing others. For example if the real working directory on the server is `/sftpdir1/sftpdir2/user1`, the user should see it as `/` and not `/user1` like when using `chrootdirectory`: when I login via FileZilla I should find as shown in the image below [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pP0H.png) where I can upload and download files.

Update: why not setting chrootdirectory in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

If I have more then on user assigned to the same group, so having the same `chrootdirectory`, any user among will see others' working directory. Or by logging in I don't want the user to see others' dir nor the tree of his/her own working directory: just find `/` like shown in the image.

Comment: what is your FTP server?

Comment: this should be covered by 1) chroot section of `man sshd` and 2) inside a `match user user1` section in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: @binarysta am using the internal-sftp

Comment: @Archemar  the chrootdirectory must be root-owned, or I want something just like the chrootdirectory but where the user (other then root) can modify it (upload and download files mainly)

Comment: be sure to check, chroot dir is root owned, but user can use it through ssh/sftp

Comment: see some details in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/542072/how-does-ssh-chroot-works

Comment: I would have a look at Linux **namespaces**, also check out tools like [nsjail](https://github.com/google/nsjail) for isolation and security.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1246146/point-an-sftp-user-to-its-working-directory-without-listing-other-users-directo

Answer (score 1):

You have to accept that your users will not be able to write to the `/` they see. Thus you cannot really make their home directory their chroot directory. If you do not mean home directory by "working directory" then you don't have to care. Just create directories

```
/sftproot
   |__ user-1
   |     |___ rw-dir
   |__ user-2
   |     |___ rw-dir
```

and set `ChrootDirectory /sftproot/%u`. The `user-x` directories are writable only by root. No user can see the chroot directory of any other user.

### using home directories

If you want the users to see their home directories then create the same directory structure, I would suggest different names, though

```
/sftproot
   |__ user-1
   |     |___ user-1
   |__ user-2
   |     |___ user-2
```

and make bind mounts like

```
mount --bind   /home/user-1   /sftproot/user-1/user-1
```

This can be done via `fstab` entries, too.

Comment: I've just mentioned `chroot` simplify explaining my prob although I don't think it is solved using chrootdirectory.. . I know chrooted directory won't appear for users, but every thing created under it will and I don't want that to happen. I want every user to point directly to  his working as if it is the root